# call api after previous api execution completed in express js with response of previous api

Tags: node.js, api, express, dynamic, node-modules

I am new to Node Js and Express js, and i need to implement fucntionality like call second api after first api execution completed and call second api with the response of first api.

It's just a demo, API counts can be 100 or 200, but i need to implement Dynamically in node js.

How would i approch this?

```
// 1st API
api.get(/one, (req, res) => {
     res.send('Hello')
})

// 2nd api
api.get(/second + one, (req, res) => {
      res.send('world')
})
```

As i have told you api count can be 50 or it can be 100, how to implement this.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined the endpoints then this might help you...

```
router.get('route', one, two);

one = (req,res,next) => {
next();
};

two = (req,res) => {
res.send('text');
};
```

Its better if u define the rotues seperately  in a routes file and the functions seperately in a controller file. The router object used above is an express router object.

Comment: second api response does not include response of first api in you example, i need to do this funtionality

Comment: i dont get u..? u want to send response from both the functions?.. if yes pass the result as a 'req.response =  ' and access it in the forthcoming functions